# When I add a new item in Listview previous values ​​are deleted

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin

When I add a new item in my ListView it is losing the values ​​that existed. It appears only the new value that was added. The goal is to add a new value without losing existing ones.My Code:

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();
void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;

    string edttxNewItem = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.newItem).Text;

    ListView listItems = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListOfItems);

    list.Add(edttxNewItem);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, list);

    listItems.Adapter = adapter;

    listItems.DeferNotifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unfamiliar about `xamarin`,but it seems that you are trying to create listview instance each time on `btnAddItem_Click`.

So initialise  `listItems` in `oncreate` method as

```
 listItems = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListOfItems);
```

and define `listItems` as class variable.

And also set `adapter` outside of `btnAddItem_Click`,let say in `OnCreate` method.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, list);
```

In `btnAddItem_Click` just add `edttxNewItem`  in `listItems` and do `notifydatasetchanged` equivalent in `xamarin`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click in the button you are instantiating a new arraylist (List list = new List();). So, every previous values in the array are deleted

Comment: I remove, but the before values is deleted. The listview is populate in begin app.